# Regarding reset document ID sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-id

We have migrated sharepoint document from On premise to SharePoint online using ShareGate. The library contain Document ID. After migrated to SharePoint online, we identified that some of Document ID have inconsistent format.

Document ID Format that we expected: NTSOPS-1059778161-01. Couple of document have Document ID ie. NTSOPS-765-05

I understand when you migrated, it retain the number of old Document ID prefix. But to get inconsistent that I am not sure how it happen. If we tried to upload new document it will pickup format that we expected.

My questions

- If I attempt to reset the Document ID, will it change number after NTSOPS or it will change number after NTSOPS-1059778161?
- Is the rest document ID will re-arrange the Document ID again. For example, if the document have Document ID ie. NTSOPS-1059778161-01. Does after reset will have different number i.e NTSOPS-1059778161-02?
- Is there anyway to reset the document that have document ID NTSOPS-765-05 only?
- Any other impact resetting the DocumentID?

Comment: There is an option that you can only reset the document id begin with those characters. Under site collection and Document ID settings